# Android. Google Play Services Saved games API

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm on the way to implement the Cloud Backup of progress that player achieved in the game so Saved Games function provided by Google Play Services looks like what I need.
After reading [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) documentation page about Saved Games I realized that it is not exactly what I need. Following the guide I have to show the new Activity for user where he's saving/loading the game progress, but I dont want to do that.
According to my idea no additional activities should be displayed, I want to do this on the background as non-visible for player task. Is there any way to do this the way I want?
I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Play Games support automatic saving and loading. According to this video: [Game On!: Cloud Save](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QF8gPZa6A0k)

7:26 of the video:

> "the game does save to the cloud automatically"

and 7:55 of the video:

> "And I'm just going to force a Cloud Load here by going into the Cloud Load menu. Notice that normally this would happen automatically"

What you have read in the document is the force save and load that can be seen in the Cload Save video.

If you notice:

> Loading Saved Games
>
> - To improve your game's performance, you are encouraged to perform saved game loading as a background operation rather than in the main thread. One way to do this is by using an AsyncTask and override its doInBackground() method to open the saved game.

Here are github that can help you with save games implementation:

- [Google Play game services - Android Samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)
- [AutoSaveUnitySample](https://github.com/claywilkinson/AutoSaveUnitySample)
- [Google Play Games plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not using Unity, so I rly dont think that the connected API will do what they say at 7:26. I need to implement at least what to save and when.
p.s. I'm using libgdx+java in my game